# button form for header sticky by javascript html laravel

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

There are **two buttons** on that **blades** (Laravel). The button (**.btn-main**) works in the **main**, but the button (**.btn-header**) in the **header** does not work.

I mean when i click the button (**.btn-header**) in the **header**, it does nothing and does not save in the database.

I know it is about the **form**.

inc/header.blade.php

```
<div class="sticky fixed">
<button type="submit" class="btn-header">Save</button>
</div>
```

index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<main>
<form action="{{ route('post.update', $post->id) }}" method="POST">
    @method('PUT')
    @csrf
    <input type="text" name="title" value="Title...">
    <input type="text" name="content" value="This is a test.">
    <button type="submit" class="btn-main">Save</button>
</form>
</div>
@endsection
```

app.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
<header>
@include('inc.header')
</header>
@yield('content')
</body>
</html>
```

I want the **buttons** to work on both sections (**header** and **main**) and store the information in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your header button doesn't do anything because it is not part of/inside the form. You can however use a [form attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-form) for your header button to work. Add an `id` attribute to your `<form>` element and point the `form` attribute in your button to that same `id`.

Your form:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<main>
<form action="{{ route('post.update', $post->id) }}" method="POST" id="myForm">
    @method('PUT')
    @csrf
    <input type="text" name="title" value="Title...">
    <input type="text" name="content" value="This is a test.">
    <button type="submit" class="btn-main">Save</button>
</form>
</div>
@endsection
```

(Added `id="myForm"` to the `<form>` element.)

Your header button:

```
<div class="sticky fixed">
<button type="submit" class="btn-header" form="myForm">Save</button>
</div>
```

(Added `form="myForm"` to the button.)

Edit: make sure there is no other `id="myForm"` on your page, choose a different unique name if so